# Runnable jar file, but the file is not synchronized in the linux server

Tags: java, linux, jar

I have a runnable `jar` file in the Linux server, but it is always an old version when I transfer the new version into the server by ftp. It seems the XML config file is old. So, there is some caching folder in the Linux? But where it is?

Comment: We will need some more information. What command do you use for copying? To which location do you copy? How do you run the jar file? Also keep in mind that Linux is case sensitive. `Foo.jar` and `foo.jar` are two distinct files.

Comment: Hi, Christian, I am sorry for this question ,seems , it is not a problem. Another problem cause the Jar file collapse, but not the file synchronization problems.